# Submit Spring job to same Spring context

Tags: spring-batch

Is it possible that I load Spring context in standalone JVM and submit all Spring batch to the loaded Spring context?

I am trying to avoid spring context loading for each spring job submission as I have resource which takes long time to load which ultimately slows down spring context loading.

I have below code in main method of class. I invoke the class through CLI by passing jobname which I want to invoke

```
public class SpringBatchJobRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            parseArguments(args);
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:com/demo/batch/context/spring-batch-context.xml");
            JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
            Job job = (Job) context.getBean(jobName);
            JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder();
            builder.addDate("date", new Date());
            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, builder.toJobParameters());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    static void parseArguments(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            jobName = args[0];
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please specify job name.");
        }
        if (args.length > 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
                String[] keyValue = args[i].split("=");
                jobParameters.setProperty(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a Spring application context can contain multiple job definitions. Once your application context is loaded, you can get job beans and launch them as needed.

Comment: will spring context loaded for multiple jobs? or it will be shutdown after we launch one job? I have multiple job definitions in one spring context. When I submit job, it loads spring context and shutdowns context as soon as job finishes its execution.

Comment: What is the trigger to launch a job? How do you run a job? In Spring Batch Admin for instance, the Spring context is loaded only once with all job definitions and then jobs are run on demand or in a scheduled manner. For a standalone app, you need to make sure your application context is not shutdown after the execution of a job, that's why I'm asking how are you planning to launch jobs?

Comment: added code in question which I am using to invoke job through CLI

Comment: I see, this is not going to work as you want it, you need to start your JVM and keep it running waiting for requests to launch jobs (just like in Spring Batch Admin, but in standalone mode). Passing the job name as argument to the JVM works only the first time, you need some way to communicate the request to the running JVM (through a db table, rest endpoint, queue, etc)